# Tinder Like animation view and adding like, dislike buttons in android

Tags: image, animation, android-cardview

HI In my project am working with tinder like view to like and dislike buttons, I have seen some library's but I didn't get solution , can you please share me any thing relevant code for this to me,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards. It's probably what you are looking for. I hope this helps